# Why does Rstudio's console not accept changes set in the Appearance panel of Tools/Global Options?

Tags: rstudio, syntax-highlighting

Earlier today I fielded a question that was complaining that changing the "Console theme" in the Appearance panel of the Tools/Global Options super menu. And example of the console was offered:

[image]

Since there is not such a selection in my Appearance panel, I asked for clarification of setup details. Turned out that the setting that was being changed was Editor theme, and it further turned out that the Edit panel was being affected by that change, but the Console panel was not. So I first search SO and found that some questions about IDE highlighting had been closed as off-topic, I eventually found the answer on the Rstudio support site:

...  but some Meta discussions had been conducted that concluded that it was of general interest to coders and should be accepted. So I'm going to repost the answer that was eventually deleted by the questioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the Console is not the Editor but there is an option in the Display subpanel of the Tools/Global options/Code  panel to enable code highlighting in the Console panel:

[image]